# How can I make it bigger height tape?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://www.altradona.ro/)

On this page you will find your product boxes ... I want them higher with 10%.

I put a picture to understand what I mean.

[image]

http://i57.tinypic.com/11rvjhj.jpg

```
<ul class="products-grid one_column_4">
    <li class="item">
        <div class="regular">//some code HTML</div>
        <div class="hover">//some code HTML</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```css
.products-grid li.item { 
    float:left; 
    width:252px; 
    padding:0;
    margin:0 15px 30px; 
    position:relative;
    background:#fff; 
    border:9px solid #fff; 
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px; 
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    height:350px;    //I add this code
}
```

I tried the above code but look how they look ... not too good.

[image]

http://i57.tinypic.com/33zck8j.png

Can you tell me please how I can make the box taller without affecting the rest of the content?

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to use a div around the item and set the height of the item at 100%.
You can use the view height unit (see here : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp )

vh or vw parameters force the height or the width of an item. 1vh corresponds to 1% of the screen view. However, if you change the size of the window, it change the size of the item until it reachs the vmin parameter.